# How do I clear history of the bash logs? Also, do not log any of my users' bash logs?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell, logging

How do I do that?
I want to clear everything as well as not log anything from now on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To clear the history

```
history -c
```

To stop new bash commands being added to the history

```
unset HISTFILE
```

To stop history permanently for you

```
echo "unset HISTFILE" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

To stop history permanently for all users

```
echo "unset HISTFILE" >> /etc/profile
```

For information the history is stored in your home folder as ~/.bash_history.

Answer (score 2):

**Clear history**:
`history -c` for a single user, `find /home -name .bash_history -delete` for any user whose `$HOME` directory is in `/home`.

**Disable history**: Put `unset HISTFILE` in your `~/.bashrc` or in the global `/etc/bash.bashrc`.